# Conditional rendering with ternary operator in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to conditionally render few messages on my page. Following is the simplified code of my actual scenario.

```
<div>
    {
        isCondition1 == true ?
           'Show issue list'
        :
            isConditionA == true?
               'Show message for condition A'
            :
                'Show error message'
    }
</div>
<div>
    {
        isCondition2 == true?
           'Show team issue list'
        :
            isConditionA == true?
               'Show message for condition A'
            :
               'Show error message'
    }
</div>
```

I want to take out common things from the above and use it in the code.

```
const msgNoIssues = (
    isConditionA == true?
       'Show message for condition A'
    :
       'Show error message'
);
```

And use it as follows:

```
<div>
    {
        isCondition1 == true?
           'Show issue list'
        :
           {msgNoIssues}
    }
</div>
<div>
    {
        isCondition2 == true ?
           'Show team issue list'
        :
           {msgNoIssues}
    }
</div>
```

But it is giving an error message:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {msgNoIssues}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use
>   an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from
>   the React add-ons.

Can it be achieved without react add-ons? Is there any better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When {} is needed in JSX?

We need to use `{}` to put js expressions inside JSX, so put ternary operator inside `{}`.

> Reason of this error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Meaning of `{ msgNoIssues }` is `{ msgNoIssues: msgNoIssues }` that means you are trying to render an object with key `msgNoIssues`, that's why it is throwing the error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {msgNoIssues}).

**Solution:**

Remove `{}` around the `msgNoIssues`, write it like this:

```
<div>
    {
        isCondition1 == true ?
            'Show issue list'
        :
            msgNoIssues
    }
</div>
<div>
    {
        isCondition2 == true ?
            'Show team issue list'
        :
            msgNoIssues
    }
</div>
```

Check this Snippet (meaning of `{ a }`):

```js
let a = 10;

let obj = {a};

console.log('obj = ', obj);
```

Check the DOC: [Embedding Expressions in JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx) and [Conditional Rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator)